# What Instructions does a CPU give to DMA?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, cpu, dma

I understood on a very high level that CPU instructs DMA to fetch data from Hard Disk and load it in RAM.

Even though I am a .Net Developer and I don't need any of this in my daily job but still I don't feel good using something I don't understand (but not too deep) to a degree that I can implement myself.

What are the exact inputs to a DMA?

But how does CPU know which memory address to read in the Hard Disk and how much length to read?

Is there any CPU Instructions to read from "Cylinder Head Sector ID's" like readhdd "sector_id" ??

If there are partitions to a file or if there are erroneous sectors how does DMA know all that?

Is there a separate embedded program in a Hard Disk to figure out all this?

Where does OS Filesystem fit in this picture?

Please provide like a workflow how a CPU reads a file from disk.

Comment: The salient parameters of a DMA operation (e.g. for peripheral-to-memory transfer) are: (1) the memory address, and (2) the transfer count. Prior to the transfer, the assigned channel of the DMA controller must be configured with peripheral address, handshake mode, transfer mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer this question since when I first learned computer, I wonder that will the disk address will be loaded in to CPU register to read a disk sector? And if so since the register is 32bit, how can we read a disk larger than 4GB? I never get the answer then I forgot it until I see this question. The disk read/write process is just so mysterious for me at that time.

> I don't understand (but not too deep) to a degree that I can implement myself.

You can never implement that since it is too complex. And why don't you feel good if you can't implement it? Will you feel bad if you can't implement Linux/Windows?

> What are the exact inputs to a DMA?

Commands that inform DMA to execute some operations, mainly IO read/write operations. On high level, commands are send by some functions in the kernel, on low level, commands are data that is write into the DMA controller's registers which often contains some pointer to some memory which contain the real commands.

> But how does CPU know which memory address to read in the Hard Disk and how much length to read?
>
> Is there any CPU Instructions to read from "Cylinder Head Sector ID's" like readhdd "sector_id" ??

"memory address" here is confusing, it should be "disk address". And it is the software that do the disk read job, not the CPU, the CPU only execute instructions in the software. So there is no CPU instruction for that since CPU doesn't do that. CPU can only read/write memory locations which include the above DMA controller registers and commands in the memory.

> If there are partitions to a file or if there are erroneous sectors how does DMA know all that?

The DMA doesn't know that and doesn't care. CPU read/write memories, DMA execute commands that CPU provides. The command s are just read memory from somewhere and write it to another place. The high level software---the file system code handle the partition of a file. And if there are erroneous sectors, the hard drive will report this to the system, there won't be DMA transfers for that erroneous data any more.

> Is there a separate embedded program in a Hard Disk to figure out all this?

There is very complex embedded program in the Hard Disk. Indeed there may be DMA operations to transfer disk data from disk magnetic heads to the memory on the hard drive (e.g. 64MB cache), whose commands is sent by the CPU on the hard drive to the DMA controller on the hard drive which are both in the disk controller chip (Agere, etc). Then that CPU do some processing like IO queue management/error checks, then the DMA in the host CPU/south bridge transfer the processed sector data from disk cache to the main memory on the host.

> Where does OS Filesystem fit in this picture?

The FIle system has nothing to do with this picture. File system is about where of the disk to read/write but this picture is about the process of the read/write.

> Please provide like a workflow how a CPU reads a file from disk.

Again the CPU doesn't reads file, the software does. Basically, it is the file system software that transform file read operation (e.g read 100 bytes from 10000 bytes offset from the beginning of d:\1.txt) to hard drive sector read commands (e.g. read 10 sectors begin at Cylinder 20 Head 2 Sector 200), these sector read commands are send to the hard drive's controller chip, then the CPU on the controller chip read the sectors according to the commands then send back the sectors data back to the host system and report any errors during the  operation. The real process will be far more complex to get high performance (low CPU utilization/high read bandwidth/low latency, etc).

Indeed DMA has nothing to do with disk read, you can read disk without DMA, and you can do most memory block read/write job using DMA. DMA is just to offload the repeated block memory read/write job from CPU which is better done by hardware instead of CPU whose cycles is precious for more complex jobs.

Comment: Thank you so much.